# Web.config transforms - the missing manual

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xslt, deployment, xpath, web-config

You can read web.config transforms documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28VS.100%29.aspx) and [there](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/03/web-deployment-webconfig-transformation_23.html), but there are two white-elephants that nobody seems to discuss:

1. How do you perform a variable substitution in a `Condition` or `XPath` transform, and...
2. Can a `Locator` be *meaningfully* nested inside a `Transform`?

Let me give an example that would benefit from either of those options.  Suppose I have this:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Suppose I want to completely erase the `dependentAssembly` node, and its children, that matches the xpath `//runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly[assemblyIdentity@name='System.Web.Mvc']`.  To do that, I might want something like this:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity 
          name="System.Web.Mvc" 
          xdt:Remove 
          xdt:Locator="Condition(..[*@name=$name])" 
      />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Well obviously I made up the syntax `@name=$name` based on [xpath variable concepts](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/wiki/Variables_in_XPath), but this example demonstrates why I'd want that feature.  Is this supported?  How must I adjust my syntax to take advantage of this?  I could put in a string literal, but I just want to know if this is possible.

Another way I might try to delete the `dependentAssembly` node, is with this:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xdt:Transform="Remove">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Notice the `Transform` is on a grand-parent node, and the locator is on leaf node. Is the above legitimate?  The idea is to remove only the `dependantAssembly` node that has an internal Locator Match.

These two approaches aside, how would you go about deleting the targeting `dependantAssembly` and all its child nodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Thommy's solution worked for me, and @LifeintheGrid's solution used the actual assemblies I wanted to remove, so I combined the two and simplified to get:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly xdt:Transform="RemoveAll"
                           xdt:Locator="Condition(starts-with(./_defaultNamespace:assemblyIdentity/@name,'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools'))">
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is the namespace attribute on the assemblyBinding tag.

Removing the AspNetHelper reference works for me with this:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly xdt:Transform="Remove" 
                           xdt:Locator="Condition(./_defaultNamespace:assemblyIdentity/@name='Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.AspNetHelper')">
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: This worked and should be marked as the answer for this question.

Answer (score 3):

This code ended up working for me.  I moved the transform to the dependentAssembly node.

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding>
    <!-- ending /dependentAssembly is required or tranforms fail -->
    <dependentAssembly xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Condition(assemblyIdentity/@name='Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.HostAdapters.ASPNETAdapter')"  ></dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Condition(assemblyIdentity/@name='Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common')"  ></dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Condition(assemblyIdentity/@name='Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.ExecutionCommon')"></dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Condition(assemblyIdentity/@name='Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource')"  ></dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```